# How to display a list of image in CarouselSlider flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, carousel

I want to display a list of image in carousel slider ,data are coming from api ..How to display images coming from list.

here is my api

```
Future<List<ImageModel>> _getImageList() async {
final url =
    Uri.parse('http://45.34.15.25/API/api/v1/MerchandiseImage/GetMerchandiseImage?OrganizationId=1');
var response = await http.get(
  url,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'tenant-code': 'flatworld',
  },
);



// print(response.body);
    if (response.body.isNotEmpty) {
      final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(result);
      Iterable imageList = result["result"];
      print(imageList.length);
      return imageList.map((record) => ImageModel.fromJson(record)).toList();
} else {
  throw Exception("Failed to load data!");
}
```

}

Comment: My model class                                                                
         class ImageModel {
  String? merchandiseImageFile;
  String? weblink;
  // ImageModel(this.imgName);

  ImageModel({
  this.merchandiseImageFile,
  this.weblink,
  });

  factory ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ImageModel(
        merchandiseImageFile: json["merchandiseImageFile"],
        weblink: json["weblink"],
    );
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
By using this plug in,  you can complete.

Comment: can you please let me know by the list how will get the images

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-carousel-slider/amp/